# How to deal with strict enumerations in plain C?

Tags: c

Take a look at the following code:

```cpp
typedef enum {
    A, B, C
} Foo;

int foo(Foo x) {
    switch(x) {
        case A: return 1;
        case B: return 2;
        case C: return 3;
    }
}
```

GCC 10.2 outputs

```
<source>:11:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   11 | }
      | ^
```

This is because I can pass something like 42 to `foo`, not only `A`, `B`, or `C`. So the question is: how to tell GCC that only `A`, `B`, or `C` can be handled by the switch statement, otherwise the behavior is undefined? Compiler-specific functionality is acceptable.

Let me point some solutions that don't satisfy me. First, I could just insert `default: __builtin_unreachable();` but this would penetrate case analysis: imagine that apparently I'm adding the `D` variant and the compiler would not tell me that `D` is unhandled.

Second, I could insert `if (x > C) { __builtin_unreachable(); }` before the switch statement, but this is too impossible because `switch(x)` is actually generated by a macro which doesn't know about the variants of `Foo`, it knows nothing but some variable `x`.

Third, I could insert `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wreturn-type"`, but again, `switch(x)` is generated by a macro and this is why I cannot revert the diagnostics to the previous state by `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop`.

Fourth, I could use an array instead of `switch` but the returned expressions are not constant and are provided by a user of the macro generating `switch(x)`.

And the last one: I could write `return 42;` after the switch statement but again I want to disable the warning automatically inside the macro generating `switch(x)` because it's used extensively in my codebase.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vs7oj4vTb)

Comment: Maybe add a `default:` case?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: The OP already floated that idea.

Comment: Apparently `default:` right after `switch(x) {` works: https://godbolt.org/z/MjW1b5eWK. Interesting...

Comment: Ah, it doesn't report about the new `D` variant, sadly.

Comment: Can you change the macro to assign a variable instead of returning? Then you can return the variable after the switch.

Comment: With the sample code, you could simply write: `static inline int foo(Foo x) { return x + 1; }` — Whether that is of any relevance in the real-world code that this example is extracted from is a separate discussion.

Comment: @Barmar, yes I can, but it would induce additional boilerplate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the expressions can be arbitrary complex and have sight effects, as I pointed in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, C doesn't have the concept of strict enums. You're going to have to make some concessions.

Comment: Adding `abort();` directly after the switch ending bracket `}` could work. It's not necessarily pretty, but the statement should also never be hit.

Comment: Also, isn't this exactly what `-Wswitch` is for?

Comment: And `-Wswitch-enum` will warn about missing `case` labels for switching on an expression of enumerated type even if the `switch` has is a `default:` label. So you could add a `default:` label and compile with `-Wswitch-enum`. You could also add `-Werror=switch-enum` to make the compilation fail.

Comment: Is it *just* the `switch` statement that's macro-generated?  Not the whole `foo` function?  If that's the case, then the easiest way to get rid of the diagnostic is to put a `return some-well-defined-error-code-that-should-never-be-reached` statement after the `switch` (or the macro that generates it).

Comment: @JohnBode, unfortunately I cannot do it because the macro generates no more than `switch(x)`, the switch body is user-provided.

Comment: @IanAbbott but what if I want to skip all other enumeration variants with `default`?

Comment: You can still have a `default` with `-Wswitch-enum`. As long as the `switch` has a `case` label for all the enumerations then you will not get a warning. It is up to you what you want to do at run-time if the `default` label is reached. The code for the `default` label would either need to return something or call a `_Noreturn` function.

Comment: Example of `-Wswitch-enum` with a `default` label issuing a warning for missing case: https://godbolt.org/z/W8vasG7T4

Comment: Hm, I mean that with `-Wswitch-enum` I must specify each variant even if it's redundant, i.e. `case A: case B: my default code section`. If I specify just `default:` without `A` and `B` above, then I'll get a compilation warning.

Comment: So in other words, I want to be able to gather unnecessary variants (but those which are still defined by an enumeration) and do something for all of them, as with `default`.

Comment: I don't think there is anything that will act as a `case` label for "all other" enumerated values excluding values outside the enumeration.

Comment: If there was a `case` label for "all other" enumerated values, wouldn't that conflict with the goal of detecting "new" enumerated values that might need to be handled in a non-default way?

Comment: If I type `default` then I agree that new enumeration variants will be unhandled. However, with some solutions I am forced to always write `default`, this is the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like engaging in some light masochism, you could crudely implement exception-like behavior using `setjmp` and `longjmp`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum Foo {
  A, B, C
} Foo;

#define ENUM_OUT_OF_RANGE -1

jmp_buf env;

int foo( Foo x )
{
  switch ( x )
  {
    case A: return 1;
    case B: return 2;
    case C: return 3;
    default: longjmp( env, ENUM_OUT_OF_RANGE ); // "throw" ENUM_OUT_OF_RANGE
  }
}

int main( void )
{
  int ex;

  if ( (ex = setjmp( env )) == 0 ) // "try" block
  {
    Foo arr[] = {A, B, C, 42};

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
      printf( "value of %d = %d\n", arr[i], foo( arr[i] ) );
    }
  }
  else // "catch" block
  {
    if ( ex == ENUM_OUT_OF_RANGE )
    {
      fprintf( stderr, "foo was called with a value outside the range of Foo\n" );
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Builds with no warnings as follows (at least on my system):

```
gcc -o exceptions -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror exceptions.c
```

Output:

```
$ ./exceptions 
value of 0 = 1
value of 1 = 2
value of 2 = 3
foo was called with a value outside the range of Foo
```